# Join or aggregate strings belonging to the same group in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

Given a CSV like this, how can I combine information from the same column?

```
First,Last,Email,Group
Tim,Elfelt,tim@domain.com,Information Systems
Tim,Elfelt,tim@domain.com,Technology Training
```

Should output this, based on combining the email column

```
First,Last,Email,Group
Tim,Elfelt,tim@domain.com,Information Systems;Technology Training
```

Edit: thanks to coldspeed, working solution here:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('combinedemails.csv', encoding='utf-8',
                   usecols=['First', 'Last', 'Email', 'Group', 'List']).groupby(['First', 'Last', 'Email']).Group.apply(
    '; '.join).reset_index(name='Group')

data.to_csv('output.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `groupby` + `str.join`:

```
df.groupby(['First', 'Last', 'Email']).Group.apply('; '.join).reset_index(name='Group')

  First    Last           Email                                     Group
0   Tim  Elfelt  tim@domain.com  Information Systems; Technology Training
```